# How to limit specific IP can access my website using Devise in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I want to bind a ip to a user, so that a user can log in using only the user's specific IP. I know Devise might use sessions to controll the authentication.

And my challenge is that I have to consider the case that several users use one specific IP because they are all behind a router, sharing one IP. How can I do to allow a specific IP for several users so that they can log in to my website using only their specific IP?

Comment: each user has a allowed IP in DB? You want to do the checking at login, or it is acceptable to do it after login?

Comment: Each user has a allowed IP, but the IP column is not unique. I want to ckeck it at login.

Comment: If you are only checking this at login, you may find that by using one of several means (e.g., a mobile device) a user can change the IP they are using after they have logged in. You may want to rethink your strategy here.